# How do I render an Editor Template in MVC2 via an Ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a controller that simply needs to return a template in my EditorTemplates\ folder.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return View("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SomeTemplate.ascx", theModel);
```